# JAX WS WebServiceClient Problema

Tags: java, linux, webservice, windows, certificado-ssl

Estamos desarrollando una aplicación en java y desde hace una semanas tenemos un problema que no somos capaces de resolver.

Se trata de llamada a un webservice para obtener una serie de datos con certificados.

Hemos seguido los siguientes pasos para la creación de los artefactos y la posterior llamada

1. Lanzamos el comando wsimport en el cmd de windows

   ```
   wsimport -keep https://xxx/xxx/xxx.svc?singleWsdl -s C:\Users\mvelasco\Documents\xx\xxxx\src\main\java -Xauthfile C:\Users\mvelasco\authwsdl.txt
   ```

Es nos genera una serie de clases con las estructuras del ws y los datacontract . [image]

2. Hemos importado los certificados

   ```
   keytool -importcert -keystore "C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file <ruta certificados> -alias x
   ```
3. Hemos creado una clase con el siguiente método de llamada al ws

   ```
   private static void llamadaAlServicio() {
     IDocumentosService port = (new DocumentosService())
           .getBasicHttpBindingIDocumentosService();
     BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider) port;
     log.error("Username: "+ContextProperties.getAsiturWsUsuario());
     log.error("Password: "    +ContextProperties.getAsiturWsPassword());

     prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,
           ContextProperties.getAsiturWsUsuario());
     prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,
           ContextProperties.getAsiturWsPassword());

     ArrayOfAttachmentDTO arrAttachmentDTO = port
               .getAllAttachments("1234567");
   }
   ```

La clase DocumentoService está generada por JAX-WS

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "DocumentosService", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", wsdlLocation = "https://xxx/xxx/xxx.svc?singleWsdl")
public class DocumentosService
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "DocumentosService");

    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://xxx/xxx/xxx.svc?singleWsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
    }

    public DocumentosService() {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_QNAME);
    }

    public DocumentosService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_QNAME, features);
    }

    public DocumentosService(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_QNAME);
    }

    public DocumentosService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_QNAME, features);
    }

    public DocumentosService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public DocumentosService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     returns IDocumentosService
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentosService")
    public IDocumentosService getBasicHttpBindingIDocumentosService() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentosService"), IDocumentosService.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param features
     *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
     * @return
     *     returns IDocumentosService
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentosService")
    public IDocumentosService getBasicHttpBindingIDocumentosService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentosService"), IDocumentosService.class, features);
    }

    private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
        if (DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_EXCEPTION!= null) {
            throw DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
        }
        return DOCUMENTOSSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    }

}
```

4.El PROBLEMA es que desde nuestras máquinas en local en windows conseguimos que el ws nos responda correctamente con esta implementación. Sin embargo, cuando subimos a entornos de preproducción bajo linux, no conseguimos conectar. La traza que nos aparece es la siguiente

> 2018-02-21 18:35:15,614 [Thread-22] [ WARN]
>   (com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wspolicy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector:255) ->
>   WSP0075: Policy assertion
>   "{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/policy/http}BasicAuthentication"
>   was evaluated as "UNKNOWN". 2018-02-21 18:35:15,615 [Thread-22] [
>   WARN]
>   (com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wspolicy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector:255) ->
>   WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side
>   with fitness "UNKNOWN". 2018-02-21 18:35:15,666 [Thread-22] [ERROR]
>   (com.noaris.agis.util.DocumentosServiceUtil:116) ->
>   Usernamejavax.xml.ws.security.auth.username 2018-02-21 18:35:15,667
>   [Thread-22] [ERROR] (com.noaris.agis.util.DocumentosServiceUtil:117)
>   -> Passwordjavax.xml.ws.security.auth.password 2018-02-21 18:35:15,667 [Thread-22] [ERROR] (com.noaris.agis.util.DocumentosServiceUtil:44) ->
>   Llamada al servicio GetAttachment con los datos: 593718000029818
>   2018-02-21 18:35:15,741 [Thread-22] [ERROR]
>   (com.noaris.agis.util.DocumentosServiceUtil:63) -> HTTP transport
>   error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target 2018-02-21
>   18:35:15,742 [Thread-22] [ERROR]
>   (com.noaris.agis.screens.expedientes.DetalleExpediente_DocumentacionVM:1040)
>   -> Error inesperado durante la obtenci?n de datos del servicio DocumentosService para el expediente593718000029818
>   com.noaris.agis.exception.BusinessException at
>   com.noaris.agis.util.DocumentosServiceUtil.getComunicaciones(DocumentosServiceUtil.java:65)at
>   com.noaris.agis.screens.expedientes.DetalleExpediente_DocumentacionVM$DocumentosServiceThread.run(DetalleExpediente_DocumentacionVM.java:1028)

5. Los certificados en las máquinas de preproducción están bien instalados en el carcets de java. Por lo tanto la excepción *unable to find valid certification path to requested target*, no logramos entender porqué se lanza.
6. Por otro lado, aparecen dos warn *"UNKNOWN"* cuando entra en la clase DocumentoService. Pensamos que quizás esto puede ser debido a que cuando entramos al wsdl necesitamos acreditarnos con antelación. En este caso no sabemos resolver cómo podemos insertar el usuario y contraseña antes del llamar al wsdl... si fuera necesario.

Llevamos estancados semanas con este problema. Se agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda. Un saludo y gracias

Comment: ¿Puede ser que el usuario con el que instalasteis los certificados y el usuario del proceso java/servidor web no coincidan y por permisos no pueda leer el archivo?

Comment: Parece que no pablo. Hemos comprobado y es el mismo. Gracias

Comment: Tu servidor de aplicaciones (Tomcat, glassfish, Jboss, etc) tambien debe poder leer los certificados instalados en tu equipo linux, eso puede ser el problema. Otra causa puede ser que el firewall te este bloqueando SOAP en ese equipo linux y por eso no funcione. Esas son dos posibles causas que yo conozco.